# The solid angle between two intersecting planes

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

Is there a solid angle between two intersecting planes? I assumed that there is one and found that this will be equal to 2A where A is the angle between the planes.However my friends disagree .They say that a solid angle exist in case of cones and other similar figures.Our textbook does not give much information on solid angles. Thus who is correct ; me or my friends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question!

Solid angle, as it's normally defined, is from a point.  Two planes cannot intersect at only one point.  They can only be coincident, parallel, or intersect at some (infinite) line.

What you *can* talk about, though, is a hybrid solid-angle-like angular measure that extends over all space from that line of intersection.  There would be $2\pi$ of these things, and it would look like a wedge of a circular disk along the line of symmetry.  The angular measure would cover all of the space away from the line ("*r*", if you will) and all of the space along the line ("*z*", if you will).

So if the angle between the two planes is $A$, then the space in between the planes where $A$ is included would cover the fraction $A/2\pi$ of all space.

What you have, I think, is *a* solid angular measure, but it definitely is different than *the* solid angle your friends are likely talking about.